# Length cutting through file handling

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 codes which did the same work as which i am asking , but still i didn't get any useful or better code for my data set to make it useful for me , First let me clear what i am doing .
I have `2 TEXT` files , one name as `input_num` and second  named as `input_data` as it is clear from names that `input_num.txt` have number in them , and `input_data` have data in it , these 2 files are of 8 to 10 mb , let me show you some of their part ,
This is 'input_num.txt'

```
ASA5.txt DF4E6.txt DFS6Q7.txt
```

and this `input_data.txt`

```
>56|61|83|92|ASA5
Dogsarebarking
```

These 2 are some parts of their text files , `input_data.txt` have last column which contain `ASA5` and so on , these are data from `input_num.txt` , so the program first check the last column of `>56|61|83|92|ASA5` which is `ASA5` than goto `input_num.txt` which have `5` , it contain some value in `input_num.txt` like `4` in the above , so it come back to the `input_data.txt` goto the words and cut them to 4 ,

I have 2 codes for it :
1 is

```
import os
import re
file_c = open('num_data.txt')
file_c = file_c.read()
lines = re.findall(r'\w+\.txt \d+', file_c)
numbers = {}

for line in lines:
    line_split = line.split('.txt ')
    hash_name = line_split[0]
    count = line_split[1]
    numbers[hash_name] = count
file_i = open('input_data.txt')
file_i = file_i.read()

for hash_name, count in numbers.iteritems():
    regex = '(' + hash_name.strip() + ')'
    result = re.findall(r'>.*\|(' + regex + ')(.*?)>', file_i, re.S)

    if len(result) > 0:
        data_original = result[0][2]
        stripped_data = result[0][2][int(count):]
        file_i = file_i.replace(data_original, '\n' + stripped_data)
f = open('input_new.txt', 'wt')
f.write(file_i)
f.close()
```

and the 2nd is

```
import csv
output = open('output.txt' , 'wb')
def get_min(num):
    return int(open('%s.txt' % num, 'r+').readlines()[0])
last_line = ''
input_list = []

#iterate over input.txt in sort the input in a list of tuples 
for i, line in enumerate(open('input.txt', 'r+').readlines()): 
    if i%2 == 0: 
        last_line = line
    else:
        input_list.append((last_line, line))
filtered = [(header, data[:get_min(header[-2])] + '\n' ) for (header, data) in input_list]
[output.write(''.join(data)) for data in filtered]
output.close()
```

Comment: What's your question/problem here? You say you have two working programs, and "Both programs work better but not accurate for me , mean to say not on huge data". So… what do they do wrong? What's the expected vs. observed output? Can you identify what about the output causes a problem? (And ideally give us a stripped-down sample input that reproduces it; if not, can you post the 10MB files somewhere in case someone wants to debug your code?)

Comment: Also, while you say you've chosen to use `csv` because you feel comfortable with it… you're not actually using `csv` at all. You do `import` it in one case, but you never touch it. You use a regex in one program, and apparently use complete lines without even attempting to split into columns in the other.

Comment: Finally, if the problem you're having with huge files is either "it's way too slow" or "it takes way too much memory", I'd give 1:1 odds that the problem is your `readlines()` calls. There is almost never a reason to use `readlines()`. If you just do `for i, line in enumerate(f)`, it gives you one line at a time, buffering as efficiently as possible; if you do `for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines())`, it first reads and parses the entire file in memory, and only then gives you one line at a time. This is never helpful, and often a problem.

Comment: @abarnert In one program in work when i split my `input_num.txt` into number of text files , and than it again stop working when some text file which is not numeric name appear , like `EOG6003RW`

Comment: @abarnert Yes , i can mail you that file , and update my question as well

Comment: No, don't mail it. That won't help anyone else who wants to test your code, or any future readers who think they might have similar problems. Also, email is a bad way for sharing files more than a couple megabytes. Find somewhere you can post them online, and put a URL in the question.

Comment: Meanwhile, "one program… stop working" is still not helpful. Which one stops working? What does it do? Quit with an exception? Hang forever? Give garbage results? You need to describe exactly what happened. Please read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for an idea of what a perfect question looks like.

Comment: 2nd program , it just stop working where a file with alphabet appear , and demand more txt files , it stop working and give error of text files ,

Comment: Can I ask you for the the scientific context around these files. Its sequencing data or alignments of some sort. Depending on what you are doing I can probably offer up another solution that wouldn't require you to use python... since this seems to be your issue.

Comment: Note that after your edit the info can not be unambiguously extracted from the num file. The only thing that saved it before was that the identifiers (file names) started with letters, not digits. If files like `5.txt` are there, my answer will probably not work, and no correct answer can at all be given. You'll definitely need to change the format of the num file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I could understand from the description of your problem with the first code, you want the first `N` letters in the output while in fact you get everything except the first `N` letters. This can probably be fixed by changing

```
stripped_data = result[0][2][int(count):]
```

to

```
stripped_data = result[0][2][:int(count)]
```

I also think the regular expressions used are not completely accurate. I suggest the following for the numbers:

```
with open('num.txt') as nums:
    lines = re.findall(r'\w+\.txt\s+\d+', nums.read())

numbers = {}
for line in lines:
    line_split = re.split(r'\.txt\s+', line)
    count = line_split[1]
    numbers[line_split[0]] = int(line_split[1])
```

and the following for the data:

```
with open('input_data.txt') as file_i:
     data = file_i.read()

for name, count in numbers.iteritems():
    result = re.search(r'\|{}\n(.*?)(>|$)'.format(name), s, re.S)
    if result:
        data_original = result.group(1)
        stripped_data = data_original[:count]
        data = data.replace(data_original, stripped_data)
with open('input_new.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

But note that the idea is still flawed because you can accidentally change more than one sequence when doing `replace`. Also this method is memory-inefficient because the files are read into the memory as one string. I suggest to use an iterative parser for the data, like the ones I mention below.

---

Anyway, if I had to solve this problem, I'd use [`pyteomics`](https://pyteomics.readthedocs.io/) to read and write FASTA files (because I wrote it and always have it handy).

The format of `input_num.txt` is awful, so I think the code from your first example is the  best one can do to extract the info. I made some fixes to it though:

```
import re
from pyteomics import fasta

with open('num.txt') as nums:
    lines = re.findall(r'\w+\.txt\s+\d+', nums.read())

numbers = {}
for line in lines:
    line_split = re.split(r'\.txt\s+', line)
    count = line_split[1]
    numbers[line_split[0]] = int(line_split[1])

with fasta.read('data.txt') as data:
    new_data = ((header, seq[:numbers.get(header.rsplit('|', 1)[-1])])
            for header, seq in data)
    fasta.write(new_data, 'new_data.txt')
```

---

On the other hand, since your data look more like DNA sequences and pyteomics is for proteomics, it may make more sense to use [`BioPython.SeqIO`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO):

```
import re
from Bio import SeqIO

with open('num.txt') as nums:
    lines = re.findall(r'\w+\.txt\s+\d+', nums.read())

numbers = {}
for line in lines:
    line_split = re.split(r'\.txt\s+', line)
    count = line_split[1]
    numbers[line_split[0]] = int(line_split[1])
data = SeqIO.parse(open('data.txt'), 'fasta')

def new_records():
    for record in data:
        record.seq = record.seq[:numbers.get(record.description.rsplit('|', 1)[-1])]
        yield record

with open('new_data.txt', 'w') as new_data:
    SeqIO.write(new_records(), new_data, 'fasta')
```

Comment: When i downloaded the exe of `pyteomics` for python 2.7 , it install , and when i import it from shell it import without error but when i import it in script it show me the error of no module name fasta

Comment: @Angel Does `from pyteomics import fasta` work in shell? (Also I just expanded the answer in the part about your code)

Comment: @Angel then it should work in a script, too, if you run it with the same Python installation that is used for the shell.